# Why did macOS not create a folder in the home directory?

Tags: terminal, command-line

I am using this script to create a folder under the home folder in Terminal like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -u

set -e

set -x

directory="~/backup/tex1234"

if [ ! -d "$directory" ]; then
  mkdir -p "$directory"
  echo "Directory created: $directory"
else
  echo "Directory already exists: $directory"
fi
```

How I found the folder did not create under the `~/backup/`, the folder path look like this:

```
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/retire/script/shell/database/~/backup/tex1234
```

Why was it not created under the home folder? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`~` has no special meaning within quotes, see [3.5.2 Tilde Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Tilde-Expansion).

Use

```
directory=~/"backup/tex1234"
```

instead (or `directory="${HOME}/backup/tex1234"`).

Comment: Documented in [3.5.2 Tilde Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Tilde-Expansion)

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks for the link!

Comment: For the record, as someone who regularly has to maintain shell scripts: _please_ use the `"${HOME}"` syntax whenever it's possible to do so. It's more readable and pops out more than a `~`, and most of the time will be syntax-highlighted in an editor.

Comment: So in other words, the shell will be looking for a folder that is actually named "~" instead of looking for the home directory. Now I can see that having a folder named "~" might get you into trouble, but it is legal. Having a file named "rm -rf *" is also legal and might get you into very, very bad trouble.